# 1995 Toyota Corolla Driver's Side Power Window Won't Roll Up, (Stuck in Down Position)

Tags: toyota, corolla, window

The driver's side window won't roll up. I just want to get the window up for now. I removed the rocker lever on the switch and there's a green LED that's on. The switch doesn't "click" when fully pressed, like the other 3 window switches clicks. I removed all of the components on the door panel, thinking I could just shimmy the window up with my hands, but it won't budge and I can only barely get a grip on it. Is it under tension with a spring or something? Can I disconnect something, pull the window up and then reconnect something to hold it in place? I see a mechanism that looks like it might be an encased coiled spring, with two cables going up and down and each bolted inside the door panel. On top of the possible encased spring is a black cylinder attached with two screws. I don't know if that helps.
Any information would be helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just disconnect the switch from the wiring, find the two wires (power and the one to the motor) which operate the window. When you connect the right two, the window will go up, as long as the switch (which it seems is the culprit) is what is bad. You just need a jumper wire to get between the two correct posts and it'll all work. Make sure your jumper wire is of sufficient gauge or it will heat up and cause issues for you ... especially if you're holding it.

Comment: That's a great idea! I have 12g wire, which should work. When I took the switch assembly apart, I noticed a lot of metal tabs. I assume I can find a wiring diagram, and connect power in tab to driver's window up tab?

Comment: @YesterdaysTools - Exactly right. If a wiring diagram isn't readily available, there should be one wire which provides power going out. It should be fairly easy to find as it will most likely be the thickest wire going into the plug. You can verify it with a multimeter. It should read battery voltage with the key on. From there you can test each terminal in the plug until you find the correct one to move the window up.